# How do I serve a static file using Node Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static

I was having trouble settings up a very basic static file sever using express with Node.js. I set up a simple `server.js` but cannot see any files when I load the URL `localhost:9000` in my web browser.

All I see is a page saying: `Cannot get /`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(9000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you're exposing nothing. Do you have, for example, an index.html file? Try this:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile("index.html");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you go through the NodeSchool workshoppers? They have step-by-step examples that cover this and more.

[Here is the workshop for Express](https://github.com/azat-co/expressworks).

Here is my solution for the 'static' question in the workshop.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(express.static(process.argv[3]||path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post('/form', function(req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
   res.end()
})

app.listen(process.argv[2])
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I edited to add the relevant solution code. Please undo the down vote. Thanks!

Comment: Explain why that is the solution and I will consider it, but blobs of code are no better an answer than blind links.

Comment: Sure. As per the thread of comments on the other answer here, I stated that Express CAN indeed serve static files in response to a request for a directory (in contrast to what @Alistair stated). This is an example of how to configure Express using the static() function to serve a file from a particular directory. It also corrects the code in the original post that omits the need to use path.join().

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Express does not create a directory listing. Even thought it does not list the files in the directory, it does serve them up when hitting them in the web browser.

Point the browser to the actual file:

`http://localhost:9000/public/test.html`

Originally I found this confusing because I had expected the express server to list directories; when seeing "something"... a page that said "Cannot get /" I assumed that page would normally have a list of files.

Comment: But you can actually configure express to serve a particular file in response to a request for a directory.